# How to copy image over the network from a Clonezilla server?

Tags: networking, images, clonezilla

I would like to make a disk image with Clonezilla and then copy it onto other computers with the same hardware configuration. I would prefer to boot from network and copy this image automatically.

I heard something about setting up a Clonezilla server for this purpose, but  I can't seem to find a simple tutorial on how to do this.

Can somebody direct me on how to set up this server and copy the images?

Comment: Clonezilla works independently of the operating system, as it just copies the disk itself.

Comment: Oh and have you, by chance, read [How to setup a Clonezilla server](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-SE.php)?